# Issue with docker compose: container command not found

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having an issue when trying to start multiple containers with docker-compose:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.9
ADD ./nginx-sites/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    links:
      - fpm
  fpm:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
```

When I use `docker-compose up` to start the application, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist.
```

Would love some help with this issue.

Comment: I just started looking at this as I had the same problem. If you remove the volumes section from your fpm service does it start up? (obviously without the files accessible to php-fpm, but just for interests sake)

Comment: yeah. without the volumes section under fpm, it starts up normally.

Comment: actually if i set the volumes as "./src:/var/www/html" (for both web and fpm services), the application starts, but I'm not able to access anything over localhost.

Comment: Might need to hit the IP of the boot2docker vm rather than 'localhost' if you are on Mac or Windows. Mine's set to 192.168.99.100 by default.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks a lot. I'm still not sure why the volume needs to be /var/ww/html, but it may be because of php-fpm.
If you'll post an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks! I posted it as an answer. You fixed my issue too. I needed the html folder on the end as well. I think you are right in that it has something to do with the php-fpm image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments to the original question the **php:fpm** image requires for it's volume to be set to `/var/www/html`.

If you want to use a different dir you can work around that by using your own Dockerfile (based on php:fpm). That `Dockerfile` would like this:

```
FROM php:fpm

WORKDIR /var/www
```

It seems like setting the workdir to the desired dir does the trick.

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` you would build with that Dockerfile instead of using the php:fpm image directly.

```
version: "2"
services:
  # ...
  fpm:
    build: ./path/to/dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer! The current marked answer is bogus.