# Docker compose volumes causing ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I've recently inherited a Rails project that is configured to be run using Docker in development. This is the first time using Docker and while I feel it should be easy I can't get it working.

When I try to run docker-compose up the output is:

> Creating projectmyapp_db_1
>   Creating projectmyapp_bundle_1
>   Creating projectmyapp_web_1
>   ERROR: Container command not found or does not exist.

The contents of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:   
  build: ./docker_db  

web:     
  build: .
  command: ./script/start
  volumes:  
    - .:/myapp
  ports:  
    - "3000:3000"
  links:  
    - db
  volumes_from:  
    - bundle  

bundle:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /bundle
```

During debugging I managed to narrow it down to the volumes line of my web container. If I comment out the `- .:/myapp` line docker-compose up command completes fine. I can access the site over the docker machine's IP address however for changes to the site to be reflected I have to completely rebuild the container which I'm assuming is what mounting the current directory as a volume is for.

The contents of the Dockerfile in my main application:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential locales libpq-dev nodejs git postgresql-client-9.4 imagemagick libmagickwand-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev graphviz less

RUN echo "ar_SA.UTF-8 UTF-8\nen_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
RUN localedef -i ar_SA -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias ar_SA.UTF-8
RUN localedef -i en_GB -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_GB.UTF-8

ENV LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_GB.UTF-8

RUN mkdir -p /myapp/config

WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
ADD config/database.yml.docker /myapp/config/database.yml

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /bundle

ADD . /myapp

CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

The result of docker --version is:

`Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1`

I've also found this similar issue here: [Issue with docker compose: container command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388590/issue-with-docker-compose-container-command-not-found) but don't feel like it's the same solution.

Any help would be really appreciated - while I've got my head around the basics of Docker now I can't seem to get to the bottom of the issue.

The error being thrown appears to be from here in the Docker source: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/df2b74188ec51422e84ec1dbdc58abf08c215019/api/client/run.go#L56

Answer (score 1):

`command: ./script/start` is the command to be executed inside your container, and it looks like this script is not available inside the container.

I suggest move the app files and the associated Dockerfile to the `web` folder, but leave the `docker-compose.yml` file at root. The modified `docker-compose.yml` would be

```
db:   
  build: ./docker_db  

web:     
  build: ./web
  command: myapp/script/start
  volumes:
    - ./web:/myapp
  ports:  
    - "3000:3000"
  links:  
    - db
  volumes_from:  
    - bundle  

bundle:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /bundle
```

The modified Dockerfile would be

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential locales libpq-dev nodejs git postgresql-client-9.4 imagemagick libmagickwand-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev graphviz less

RUN echo "ar_SA.UTF-8 UTF-8\nen_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
RUN localedef -i ar_SA -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias ar_SA.UTF-8
RUN localedef -i en_GB -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_GB.UTF-8

ENV LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_GB.UTF-8

WORKDIR /myapp

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /bundle

CMD rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Note that I removed all of the `ADD` command, as you will be mounting the folder from host. Make sure on the host, in the new web folder, you have the following files (rename or copy the `config/database.yml.docker` file to `config/database.yml`)

```
./web/Gemfile
./web/Gemfile.lock
./web/config/database.yml
./web/script/start
```

And any other files that should be here.

Make the `start` file executable using `chmod +x`.

Finally, run `docker-compose up`

Comment: I altered the command to `/myapp/script/start` and removed the `ADD . /myapp` line from the Dockerfile but the error remains the same.  After making the changes I ran `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` is there anything else I'd need to run?

Comment: Do you have this `/script/start` file? And what is the content? If you don't probably delete this command line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I do the contents of it are simply: http://pastebin.com/B5P03je3

Comment: Try `chmod +x ./script/start` on your host and then run docker-compose build/up. Alternatively, just add the content to the CMD section in the dockerfile, and then delete the command line from docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Possibly some progress just waiting for the gems to bundle.  Will update when I know more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No luck so far. Mounting the volume essentially seems to mask the directory so when I run `docker-compose run web bash` and list the directory it's empty. I can copy the Gemfile over and bundle fine but then my start command runs essentially in an empty directory causing the rails --help command to be invoked instead. How am I supposed to run the start command if the files are masked by the volume (root of the project in host)?